# What does "rule of construction" mean?

Tags: legal-terms

I was looking up a legal term, and found this sentence:

> An anti-lapse statute is a rule of construction in trusts and estates law.

What does "rule of construction" mean (here, and in general)?

Comment: FWIW, an anti-lapse statute is a special "rule of construction" that recognizes that the person who wrote language in a will or trust usually means something different than what the literal meaning of the words in the document and gives those words their intended rather than literal meaning, unless the document explicitly refers to the anti-lapse statute and says that it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

A [rule of construction](https://definitions.uslegal.com/r/rule-of-construction/) is a methodology or procedure for resolving ambiguities in a contract or statute.